# Change method return type to List<String> java

Tags: java, android

In my application I have a method `fetchJSONChild()` as below:

```
public List<String[]> fetchJSONChild(){

    final List<String> child;// = new ArrayList<String>();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                String data1 = "1,2,3";
                //String[] parts = new String[3];

                child = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data1.split(",")));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start(); 
    return child;
}
```

In this method I have created a list and put splitted string items on it but when I return this list, I am getting an error at this line `return child;` as below:

`Change method return type to List<String>`

How can I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: `List<String[]>` should be `List<String>`?

Comment: Your multithreaded scheme will not work.

Comment: I replace `List<String[]>` to this `List<String>` but after that I am getting another error `the local vaiable 'child' cannot be assigned` for resolving this I have assigned `final List<String> child = null;` then I am getting another error `the local vaiable 'child' cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type` at this line `child = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data1.split(",")));`.

Comment: I honestly don't see any function of the `Thread` there, except making a trouble here. If you really need to use it, then you have to convert the arrays to list manually by adding it 1-by-1, but possibly, the function has already returned the `child`, which may corrupt the data.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others you have to change `List<String[]>` to `List<String>`. You can't assign a new `ArrayList` to `child` because you declared it to be `final`. Besides that your code is really messed up and your `Thread` makes no sense. You should instead do something like this:

```
// Don't use a thread in your method.
public List<String> fetchJSONChild(){
    final String data1 = "1,2,3";
    final List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data1.split(",")));

    return child;
}

// Call your method in a thread elsewhere
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Since the method is not static, you need a reference to an object which declares this method.
        final List<String> chils = yourObject.fetchJSONChild();

        // Do something with your list
    }

}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public List<String[]> fetchJSONChild(){
```

to:

```
public List<String> fetchJSONChild(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return an `ArrayList<String>` but the return type of your method is `List<String[]>`. Notice the `[`], your method wants to return a list of arrays of strings, which is different from a list of strings.

Just change your return type to `List<String>`:

```
public List<String> fetchJSONChild()
```

Answer (score 0):

Return type should be `List<String>` That's it

Answer (score 0):

You've defined in your Signature a `List<String[]>`, so a list of String arrays.

But the List you instantiate is actually a List of Strings.
Please not that an `ArrayList` actually doesn't mean that it contains Arrays. (See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Either you change your method signature to `public List<String> fetchJSONChild()`

or you have to create Arrays of Strings within your method.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Datatype of child is `List<String>`. However return type of function is `List<String[]>` causing type mismatch.

Change return type of function to `List<String>` (and not `List<String[]>`) and it may work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in having a multithreaded design for this program. Most likely when you fix the compilation problems that others mentioned your method will always return an empty List. I would suggest not to do any mutithreading in this case.